# Primefaces onstart vs onclick

Tags: primefaces

What is the difference between `onclick` and `onstart`?

**e.g.**

```
<p:commandButton id="checkout" value="Complete Checkout" action="#{checkoutBean.checkout}" update="@form" 
    onclick="PF('blockui').block()" onstart="PF('blockui').block()" oncomplete="PF('blockui').unblock()"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

`onclick` = being invoked prior to the actual form submission / prior to the ajax call (and that's why calling `return false;` in onclick prevents the flow of form submission/ajax call - in other words onclick is called before the `action` of the button.

> The onclick event occurs when the user clicks on an element

`onstart` = being invoked after the `onclick` and its the first phase of ajax flow from client to server, once you there, your ajax has begun and you can't really stop it...

> The onstart event occurs when ajax call is about to start

---

**IMO**, you better be consistent and call your `PF('blockui').block()` code in `onstart` since you stopping it on `oncomplete` (both are ajax related phases), and keep the `onclick` usage for other purposes (maybe for some reason you would like to place a conditional statement that might call `return false;` which will prevent your ajax from being called at all.

Comment: "Primefaces User Guide 5.0" : `onstart()` - Javascript callback to process before sending the ajax request, return 
false to cancel the request. ?